# angular2 @Input() change watch?

Tags: angular

```
export class Test {
  a1: number;
  name: string;
}


@Component({
  selector: '[t1-info]',
  templateUrl: './t1component.html',
})
export class T1InfoComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() test: Test;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}

<div t1-info [test]="test"></div>
<button (click)='test.a1 = test.a1-1'>test</button>
```

or

```
http.get(....).subscribe(res=>{
   test.a1=1;
})
```

**how to watch test.a1 change？**
Similar to angular1 $Watch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can fire event on any changes made in that component using `@output()` and call any function to listen to that changes

```
export class Test {
  a1: number;
  name: string;
}


@Component({
  selector: '[t1-info]',
  templateUrl: './t1component.html',
})
export class T1InfoComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() test: Test;
  @Output() changeEvent: new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  changeEvent(){
    console.log(this.test, "Changes")
  }
}

<div t1-info [test]="test"></div>
<button (click)='test.a1 = test.a1-1'>test</button>
```

Comment: Can't auto compare? Do you want the program to trigger events?

Comment: sorey what you are to trying to say ?